# Append text to a piped file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, append

I am piping a file through bash how could I append some text to the end of it?

```
cat filename.txt | append "text to append" | final_command
```

EDIT: This has to be done without creating a new file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(cat filename.txt && echo "text to append") | final_command
```

If you don't want a newline character at the end, use `echo -n`:

```
(cat filename.txt && echo -n "text to append") | final_command
```

Comment: It would add a newline.

Comment: @Hi-Angel maybe this is what OP wanted. Anyway, I added a no-newline version to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more alternatives:

```
cat filename.txt <(echo "text to append") | final_command

final_command <(cat filename.txt; echo "text to append")
```

(assuming `final_command` can take input from an argument instead of the default stdin)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this solution is more concise:

```
echo "text to append" | cat filename.txt - | final_command
```

It is also more flexible, for instance, you can

```
echo "text to append" | cat file1.txt - file2.txt ... | final_command
```

The solution which OP chose would be awkward in the second case.